# Creating method to draw a circle using the centre of the circle and radius

Tags: c#

The method I created worked to the point that it would create a circle in a pictureBox but it would only use the coordinates of a rectangle.

I'm trying to create the following,

- Windows form with:

  - 1 pictureBox
  - 1 textBox
  - 1 button

textBox should be used to insert the radius for the circle.

```
(double input=Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text)

{
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        double input....
        double radius= Math.PI*input*input;
        Graphics paper;
        paper = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        getCircle(paper, pen, (variables for center), radius);
    }
private void getCircle(Graphics drawingArea, Pen penToUse, int xPos, int yPos, double radius);

{
}

}
```

My problem here being I have no idea how to create a circle using `Math.PI*radius*radius` with pre determined centre coordinates.

I would like to see an answer with coded method and `button_click`

Comment: look ad DrawEllipse. The reasone you probably will not get too many answers is that you are expected to do some research, try something, then ask.

Comment: Im guessing its HW and that he should draw the circle using cos/sin * radius..

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand why you are finding the area of the circle and calling it radius, but since it appears that you are using Winforms I would just use the [`Graphics.DrawEllipse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3fd63x2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method and use the rectangle you can find by subtracting the radius from the desired center.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int centerX;
    int centerY;
    int radius;

    if (!int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out centerX))
        return;
    if (!int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out centerY))
        return;
    if(! int.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out radius))
        return;

    Point center = new Point(centerX, centerY);

    Graphics paper; 
    paper = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics(); 
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black); 
    getCircle(paper, pen, center, radius); 

}

private void getCircle(Graphics drawingArea, Pen penToUse, Point center, int radius) 
{ 
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(center.X-radius, center.Y-radius,radius*2,radius*2); 
    drawingArea.DrawEllipse(penToUse,rect);
}
```

Comment: Aah nice, this works great and everything, im just not allowed to use the if command yet. 
Also, this book im using is confusing, the chapters have no real value when it comes to their questions, I have been wanting to use if since chapter 1 to keep my "programs" from crashing. But this was a really helpful answer. this is something I can change into what the book wants me to do.

Comment: @user1708501 I just used the if command to parse the string to an integer. You can use int.Parse but it will give an error if it fails or use int.TryParse without the If statement instead. Glad to be of help

Comment: I just managed to use int.TryParse in a different project. Avoiding an error. Thank you again